# What is special about 70.329862 and InputField and Number and Dynamic?

Tags: dynamic, formatting

Is this a bug (happening in V9 and V10 Windows, Linux) or not? It only happens for certain numbers and you need Number in InputField.

```
maxrange = {0., 70.329862};
InputField[Dynamic@maxrange[[2]], Number]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like it took you some time to arrive at the right digits... ;-)

Comment: Nein nein! This is from a real world project and it is a real number (molar percentage).

Comment: Clue?: `SetPrecision[70.329862, $MachinePrecision]`.  (Not sure it's the answer....)

Comment: Also, `RealDigits[70.329862]` gives same behavior. Isn't this just a property of manually-entered floating point numbers, though? The precision depends on how many significant figures you enter in. For example, `SetPrecision[70.329862000000000000, $MachinePrecision]` gives no errant digits. This is normal behavior if I recall correctly; I'm pretty sure this is explained in the documentation somewhere, although I can't remember which article it's in.

Comment: Maybe it is just a matter of change $MachinePrecision to MachinePrecision, since `SetPrecision[70.329862, MachinePrecision]` gives 70.329862

Comment: I do think this is a bug of `InputField[ ..., Number]` . I really really wish WRI would stop doing anything new for two or three years and just fix all the old bugs...

Comment: Try entering `10000000000000000.`. Ugh. (Warning message is generated.)

Comment: `Off[NumberForm::sigz]` fixes this

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem relates to the granularity of `MachinePrecision` numbers.

The number `70.329862` is represented as an integer times a power of `2`:

```
x0 = SetPrecision[70.329862, Infinity]

(* 4949024067128413/70368744177664 *)
```

(The denominator is `2^46`.)  The machine numbers near this number do not allow for the representation of `70.329862` with `$MachinePrecision` (`15.95..`) number of digits.

```
den = Denominator[x0];
N[x0 + Range[-2, 2]/den, $MachinePrecision]
(*
  {70.32986199999998, 70.32986199999999,
   70.32986200000001, 
   70.32986200000002, 70.32986200000003}
*)
```

The number `70.329862` is closest to its binary machine representative, which can be seen if we display more digits:

```
N[x0 + Range[-2, 2]/den, 20]
(*
  {70.329861999999977229, 70.329861999999991440,
   70.329862000000005651, 
   70.329862000000019862, 70.329862000000034072}
*)
```

Now let's consider what the displayed string in the `InputField` should be.  Should it be the 16-digit number closest to the machine number, or should it be the closest simple number?  `InputField` seems to do the first, dropping final zeros.  In a numeric sense, it is the most precise representation.  For that reason, WRI may feel justified in keeping to the present behavior of `InputField`.  On the other hand, it would be nice if there were an option to `InputField` to control the display of numbers.  I could not find one.  If one could set it to display the normal front-end `StandardForm`, then `70.329862` and `70.3299` would both be displayed as `70.3299`.  In a sense, one would not know what the input is, only what it is near.  In some cases that might be ok.

**More than one needs to know**

For what it's worth, here is how the behavior comes about.  The `InputField` calls `` FrontEnd`Private`ToSimpleNumberBoxes `` to convert the number to a string.  It in turn calls `NumberForm[val, Infinity, ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]`.  For a machine precision number `val`, it will return up to 16 digits, which is how many are needed to distinguish machine reals.

Determined people can redefine `` FrontEnd`Private`ToSimpleNumberBoxes ``, which is not `Protected`.  I don't know if that means it is safe to redefine.  I would assume it's NOT safe.  Be that as it may, the following fixes the toy example `InputField`.  It will display  some distinct numbers as if they were the same because it shows a number of digits that is less than the precision.  And it will affect all input fields.  Thus I would say this is not a solution, at least not a good one.  It does suggest that no easy fix is likely to be found.

```
FrontEnd`Private`ToSimpleNumberBoxes[FrontEnd`Private`value_?NumberQ, StandardForm] := 
 ToString[NumberForm[FrontEnd`Private`value, 
   Floor[Precision[FrontEnd`Private`value]],
   ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]]
```

**For everyday use**

Instead of messing with system functions, one can control the behavior of `InputField` within `Dynamic`:

```
InputField[
 Dynamic[ToString[
   NumberForm[maxrange[[2]], Floor[Precision[maxrange[[2]]]], 
    ExponentFunction -> (Null &)]], 
  If[StringMatchQ[#, FrontEnd`Private`ValidNumberRegex], 
    maxrange[[2]] = ToExpression[#]] &],
 String]
```

Then one can really control the input and output formatting as desired.  (I don't believe this will work with restricted CDFs, though.)

Comment: Great! This is just perfect for everyday use!

Comment: @RolfMertig  I added another workaround.

Comment: I prefer Number as second argument of InputField rather than String. This way users really only can enter numbers. If I put your FrontEnd`Private`ToSimpleNumberBoxes definition into the Initialization of the DynamicModule things just work in PlayerPro 9.0.1 (still no PlayerPro 10, unfortunately. But I am sure we will enjoy it soon).

Comment: @RolfMertig The way the `Dynamic` in the `InputField` is set up, an edit is *accepted* only if the input string matches ``FrontEnd`Private`ValidNumberRegex`` (the same as `Number` in the second argument), although the user may enter any characters.  I understand the difference might be unsatisfactory.  The main thing to beware is that I do not know what front-end functions depend on `ToSimpleNumberBoxes`.  (As it is an output formatting function, it might not matter that much.)

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT**

Input gets different rounding to machine-precision real if it's written in arbitrary precision!

```
RealDigits[70.329862, 2]

(* {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
     0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
     1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, 7} *)

RealDigits[
 SetPrecision[70.329862000000000000, $MachinePrecision], 2]

(* {{1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
     0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
     1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 7} *)
```

Precise expansion would indicate that without using four bits of extra precision, both are 0.5 ulp off:

```
Flatten@RealDigits[70329862/1000000, 2]~Take~57

(* {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1} *)
```

In this case, the form without arbitrary precision is closer to the true value, but that rounding up pushes the trailing 1 into the decimal back-conversion.

**Original answer:**

In Mathematica, `MachinePrecision` reals are represented as double-precision (53 bit mantissa) binary floating point numbers. The critical point here is not so much "floating point", but "binary."

Consider the following:

```
RealDigits[0.1, 2, 53]

(* {{1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
     0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
     0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, -3} *)
```

Since 1/10 is not representable with sum of finite amount of integer powers of two, this floating point representation is actually only approximate!

There are heuristics in conversion of binary representation to sufficiently precise decimal notation. Occasionally selection of these heuristics causes rounding on lowest bits of binary representation to creep up the way you see it now. For instance, do you want output "decimal-looking" numbers to be pretty, or to get faithfully rounded transcendentals, or rationals expanded to correct recurring forms? There's no single easy answer.

You may also ask: why not use absolutely precise conversion from binary to decimal representation? Well, it has its' drawbacks. Consider precise decimal expansion of `MachinePrecision` `0.1`:

```
N[FromDigits[First@RealDigits[0.1, 2, 53], 2]/2^56, 60]

(* 0.100000000000000005551115123125782702118158340454101562500000 *)
```

(Only some of those digits are necessary to precisely represent the binary floating-point value. As @MichaelE2 shows, there are intervals on which all values are valid representations; what to pick?)

Comment: You just beat me by a couple of minutes! :)  Well, I guess I'm saying some things that are different at least.  I guess I don't need to delete?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I hope these answers complement each other. :)

Comment: @kirma: very nice analysis. But I am going to accept Michael E2's answer because it provides a fix ( the greatest thing of M is that knowledgable users can fix bugs way ahead of WRI).

Comment: @RolfMertig No problem. :)