# Setting display precision in InputField with Dynamic variable

Tags: output-formatting, gui-construction, precision-and-accuracy, inputfield

I have a following code:

```
Manipulate[
    Column@{
       InputField[Dynamic[coefA], Number, ImageSize-> 130]
       (*InputField[Dynamic[SetPrecision[coefA,3]], Number, ImageSize->130]*), 
       Slider[Dynamic[coefA], {-10., 10., .01}, ImageSize -> 130]
    },
    {{coefA, 0}, ControlType -> None}, 
    AppearanceElements -> None]
```

I want both `Slider` and `InputField` to be able to modify `coefA` variable, however I would like to have a special formatting inside `InputField` - to 2 decimal points (like: 1.2358->1.24). The commented line works... for the `Slider`. It can modify variable and it is printed correctly, but I loose ability to modify it via `InputField` because:

> "Tag SetPrecision in SetPrecision[-1.74,3] is Protected."

Any ideas how it can be done?

Comment: Is this enough? `Dynamic[SetPrecision[coefA, 3], (coefA = #) &]`

Comment: This is closely related topic: [6259](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6259/5478) but solutions from there are not working with `Number` type `InputField`.

Comment: I've noticed that you haven't accepted any of answers to you questions. Are they missing something. Please, take a [**tour**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Oh I'm sorry i totally forgot I asked this question here! You suggested the same solution as my teacher so i totally forgot to thank you - Thanks, @Kuba. Im gonna mark this as '[SOLVED]' now (how to do so...? :D)

Comment: No worries, I just wanted to tell you about the accept mark because sometimes users are not aware of it.

Comment: About how to do so, take a look at the link 'tour' I gave in the previous comment.

Comment: @michelson You can marked this question, and any other of your questions, as SOLVED by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/). I noticed none of your question have accepted answer. Also, in case you don't know, when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you can use very general [answer from Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63327/5478) (*the bottom of his answer*) or this quick fix:

```
Column@{
    InputField[Dynamic[SetPrecision[coefA, 3], (coefA = #) &], Number], 
    Slider[Dynamic[coefA], {-10., 10., .01}]
}
```

Keep in mind that precision is not closely related to number of digits after decimal point.

To have `10.12` and `1.23` at once you have to use `NumberForm[var, {Infinity, 2}]` and approach from linked answer.